# Symfony doctrine, How reduce number of queries

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a lot of queries in my profiler, So I try to add join() and select() in my repository for reduce the number of queries like usual

But this time, I reload the page and I have more queries than before

```
/**
 * @return ForumDiscussion[] Returns an array of Page objects
 */
public function findBySortUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        // Doesn't work, make more queries
        // ->select(array('f', 'user', 'forumCategory'))
        // ->leftJoin('f.user', 'user')
        // ->leftJoin('f.forumCategory', 'forumCategory')
        ->orderBy('f.updatedAt', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Someone know why it's happen ?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible that your User entity has some type of one to one or many to one relationship, and for that reason you are seeing other queries. You could add the corresponding joins or mark these relations as extra_lazy in your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your User entity must have relations to other Entities. By default Doctrine uses the "LAZY" fetch mode when fetching entities.

The "EXTRA_LAZY" will reduce the number of queries by returning dummy objects instead of actual hydrated entities concerning the User related objects.

To use the "EXTRA_LAZY" fetch mode in the User entity you can just pass it as a parameter of your association annotations.

Here is a link to the official documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html